# IOTA Trinity Wallet Installation fails

Tags: wallet

the installation of the Trinity Wallet does not work. After the download, a white window appears without input possibility or registration

Comment: can you share some more details about your configuration? Mobile app (Android / iOS) or Desktop app (Windows/Linux/Mac)?